# Merge Pdf Files Using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, merge, pdfbox

I have to merge two pdf Files using PdfBox of Apache. I have taken physical pdf files to do so.
Below is the code:

```
PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
ut.addSource(path1);
ut.addSource(path2);
ut.setDestinationFileName(path3);
ut.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
```

Files are merged perfectly but then have some constraints as below:

1. I am creating 1st file in the code itself,so it is PDDocument object.
2. The file which I have to merge with 1st file is in byte array format.
3. I don't need to save the merged files but need convert it as byte array.

Please anyone help me achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 10):

Call [`PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDDocument destination, PDDocument source)`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/PDFMergerUtility.html#appendDocument(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument,%20org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument)) instead of merge. To load from a byte array, call `PDDocument.load(array)`.

**Btw**: I'd discourage to merge PDDocument objects that you created yourself, this fails if you have font subsets (see issue [PDFBOX-3243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3243)). Better save them (e.g. in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`) and reload and then merge. To get a byte array from a ByteArrayOutputStream, use [`ByteArrayOutputStream.tobytearray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()).

Comment: do you have an example for the `ByteArrayOutputStream` approach? I tried to save two docs into two streams, combined the arrays and reloaded the combined bytes into a new document. However, it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        doc.save(baos);
        doc.close();
        doc = PDDocument.load(baos.toByteArray());`

Comment: So you meant one should save and reload the self-made `PDDocument`? ... and your comment was not about merging documents by combining `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s. Right?

Comment: Yes, you should save and reload the self-made PDDocument before merging.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can convert it into byte array

```
PDDocument.load(path3.getBytes()));
```