# Unable to merge streams with PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Currently i am able to merge two PDF files when using java.io.File but unable to do merge them when using input and outputstreams.

Below the code works and generates merged PDF with success.

```
File mainDoc = new File(path...);
File additionalDoc = new File(path...);

PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
pdfMerger.setDestinationFileName(path + "/merged.pdf");
pdfMerger.addSource(mainDoc);
pdfMerger.addSource(additionalDoc);
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(null);
```

I then tried to do the same by using streams.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream mainDocStream = new FileInputStream(path...);
InputStream additionalDocSteam = new FileInputStream(path...);
PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
pdfMerger.addSource(mainDocStream);
pdfMerger.addSource(additionalDocSteam);
pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(out);
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(null);
```

The code above when reaching line *pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(null);* throws following exception :

> java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line    at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2005)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:1988)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:269)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1143)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1059)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:263)

At last i tried to follow this answer ([Merge Pdf Files Using PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595137/1918516)) as an example but my generated pdf does not seem to have merged those two pdfs.
This is the code that i tried.

```
public InputStream createPDF() {
    try{
        // Note, i have also tried to use java.io.File instead of an 
        // InputStream but the result was the same
        // File mainDoc = new File(path...);
        // PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(mainDoc);
        InputStream pdfInputStream = null;
        InputStream mainDocStream = new FileInputStream(path...);
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(mainDocStream);
        InputStream additionalDocSteam = new FileInputStream(path...);
        PDDocument additionalDocument = PDDocument.load(additionalDocSteam);
        PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();

        pdfMerger.appendDocument(additionalDocument, document);
        document.save(out);
        document.close();
        PDDocument.load(out.toByteArray());

        pdfInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

    }catch(...){
        ....
    }
    return pdfInputStream;
}
```

The code above does generate a PDF but the newly created PDF contains only the content of the main document and not from the second one. So it looks that i am missing something and the documents are not merged.

Comment: Since i do not want to open a new question. Are there any advantages in using appendDocument  instead of mergeDocuments ?

Comment: Stacktrace added.

Comment: Thanks; this stacktrace is exactly the one you get when you open an empty file. Merging works for me with (non empty) streams.

Comment: Re your question in the comment: I'd suggest using files, PDFBox will take care of closing them. With streams you must close them yourself.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i am not sure this is caused due to an empty file. What i want to say, in all my code samples that i provided the file location as also the files that i use are constant. It is the only thing that i have not change in all the scenarios.  I do not mind to elaborate to find the why this exception is thrown in case you are interested.  Thank you for all your support.

Comment: Please add `System.out.println(mainDocStream.available() + " " + additionalDocSteam.available());` before calling `pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(null);`. I wonder if your code is part of "something bigger", e.g. that maybe the files are being written by another process?

Comment: Both mainDocStream.available() and additionalDocSteam.available() return "0" which means that i most propably have something wrong in my code? Yes my code is part of something bigger which unfortunately i cannot publish. The only change i do to reproduce this error, is add the stream inside pdfMerger.addSource(mainDocStream); The stream i use is exactly the same as seen on my very last code sample in my question InputStream mainDocStream = new FileInputStream(path...); As i mentioned, this code does not throw any exception although i use a stream but also does not merge the files.  .

Comment: Yes it is weird. Maybe under some conditions you'll get similar problems with using files too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution, but i still cannot understand what is going wrong when using streams. In detail:

While the following code throws an exception (***java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line)*** :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream mainDocStream = new FileInputStream(path...);
InputStream additionalDocStream = new FileInputStream(path...);
PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
pdfMerger.addSource(mainDocStream);
pdfMerger.addSource(additionalDocStream);
pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(out);
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(null);
```

When using a File in the addSource method, everything seems to work as required.

```
public InputStream createPDF() {
    InputStream pdfInputStream = null;

    try{
        File mainDoc = new File(...);
        File additionalDoc = new File(path...);
        PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
        pdfMerger.addSource(mainDoc);
        pdfMerger.addSource(additionalDoc);
        pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(out);
        pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(null);
        pdfInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }catch(...){
        ...
    }
    return pdfInputStream;
}
```

Now, why the first approach using streams throws an exception while using directly the file works, is something i would also like to know.

Comment: *"why the first approach using streams throws an exception while using directly the file works, is something i would also like to know."* - If you don't consider your question to be properly answered without that, you should post your current solution as edit to the question, not as answer...