# JAVA Merge 2 PDF byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, pdfmerger

I receive two PDFs, each as a byte array. So now I have 2 arrays, a[] and b[].
I concatenate them and save them to c[].
When I convert c[] to a PDF, only the 2nd file shows up. When I check the length of c[], it is len(a[]) + len(b[]).

I found [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288556/second-byte-overwrites-first-byte-while-merging-the-pdf) about this for different programming languages, and they say that I can't just concatenate them like this, we need to use a PDF authoring library. Since I receive byte arrays to begin with, is there anything else that could work in my situation?

Comment: They are right. Just as concatenating the bytes of two images will not give a larger image. But PDF libraries may read a byte array then two PDF objects may be merged. There often exist examples.

Comment: You can use openpdf | https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/wiki/Tutorial to load both documents(byteArray) and then do the merge of individual pages.

Also if you can use thirdparty libraries you can use pdfbox as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589590/merge-pdf-files-using-pdfbox

Comment: We're not keeping the process real time anymore, changing it to a batch job, so that takes care of things.
Thank you both for your time. I was going through OpenPDF when my lead realized it wasn't required of us to do it in real time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just concatenate the byte arrays.

You can find a couple of solutions for merging PDF files here [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java)

If you have the PDF files, you can just use PDFMergerUtility of pdfbox.

```
PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
ut.addSource(...);
ut.addSource(...);
ut.addSource(...);
ut.setDestinationFileName(...);
ut.mergeDocuments();
```

If the PDF files are not available, you can just use the other solution with itext

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

/**
 * This class is used to merge two or more 
 * existing pdf file using iText jar.
 */
public class PDFMerger {

   static void mergePdfFiles(List<InputStream> inputPdfList,
                             OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception{
      //Create document and pdfReader objects.
      Document document = new Document();
      List<PdfReader> readers = 
              new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
      int totalPages = 0;

      //Create pdf Iterator object using inputPdfList.
      Iterator<InputStream> pdfIterator = 
          inputPdfList.iterator();

      // Create reader list for the input pdf files.
      while (pdfIterator.hasNext()) {
          InputStream pdf = pdfIterator.next();
          PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
          readers.add(pdfReader);
          totalPages = totalPages + pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
      }

      // Create writer for the outputStream
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

      //Open document.
      document.open();

      //Contain the pdf data.
      PdfContentByte pageContentByte = writer.getDirectContent();

      PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage;
      int currentPdfReaderPage = 1;
      Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

      // Iterate and process the reader list.
      while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
        PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();
        //Create page and add content.
        while (currentPdfReaderPage <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
              document.newPage();
              pdfImportedPage = 
              writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader,currentPdfReaderPage);
              pageContentByte.addTemplate(pdfImportedPage, 0, 0);
              currentPdfReaderPage++;
        }
        currentPdfReaderPage = 1;
     }

     //Close document and outputStream.
     outputStream.flush();
     document.close();
     outputStream.close();

     System.out.println("Pdf files merged successfully.");
   }

}
```

Comment: I spoke to my company about this. They're not looking at paying for software licenses at the moment. We're not keeping the process real time anymore, changing it to a batch job, so that takes care of things.
Thank you for your time taken to answer this.

Comment: Hi Sudansh, am into same situation . not able to concat two byte arrays into 3rd array and print pdf of 3rd array. Any suggestions how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still looking for such solution, try this:

//Suppose we want to merge one pdf with another main pdf

```
          InputStream is1 = null;



          if (file1 != null) {

                 FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);

                 byte[] file1Data = new byte[(int) file1.length()];

                 fis1.read(file1Data);

                 is1 = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(file1Data);

          }



          //

          InputStream mainContent = <ur main content>



          org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument mergedPDF = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument();

          org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument mainDoc = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(mainContent);

          org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility merger = new org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility();



          merger.appendDocument(mergedPDF, mainDoc);



          PDDocument doc1 = null;



          if (is1 != null) {

                 doc1 = PDDocument.load(is1);

                 merger.appendDocument(mergedPDF, doc1);

                //1st file appended to main pdf");

          }

         



          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

          mergedPDF.save(baos);
```

//Now either u save it here or convert into InputStream if u want

```
          ByteArrayInputStream mergedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```